# Assumptions leading to the mutual independence of random variables

Tags: probability, bayesian, independence

I know that $P(AB) = P(A)P(B) \land P(BC) = P(B)P(C) \land P(AC) = P(A)P(C)$ does not imply $P(ABC) = P(A)P(B)P(C)$.

But does $P(ABC) = P(A)P(BC) = P(B)P(AC) = P(C)P(AB)$ imply $P(ABC) = P(A)P(B)P(C)$?

I don't see a way to prove it, I think the product rule alone is not enough, but whatever I do I seem to be running in cycles.

I did notice that $P(C|A) = P(C) \land P(C|B) = P(C)$ does not follow from $P(C|AB) = P(C)$. The counterexample is to make $A$ and $B$ nudge the posterior in opposite directions. For example, let $P(A) = P(B) = P(D) = 0.5$, and $C =$ "at least two of $A, B, D$ are true". Now knowing $A$ and $\lnot B$ doesn't tell us anything $C$, but knowing $\lnot B$ or $A$ alone does.

I wrote an experiment in python that makes me believe the implication is true. It generates random distributions, and enforces the above equalities for a number of iterations (it seems to converge quite quickly):

```
import numpy as np

r = 0.0
for itit in range(100):
    P = np.random.random(size=(2,2,2))
    s = np.sum(P)
    P = P / s
    for it in range(50):
        for i in range(2):
            for j in range(2):
                for k in range(2):
                    pi = P[i,:,:].sum()
                    pj = P[:,j,:].sum()
                    pk = P[:,:,k].sum()
                    pij = P[i,j,:].sum()
                    pik = P[i,:,k].sum()
                    pjk = P[:,j,k].sum()
                    P[i,j,k] = (pi * pjk + pj * pik + pk * pij) / 3.0
                    P = P / np.sum(P)

    r = max(r, abs(P[1,:,:].sum() * P[:,1,:].sum() - P[1,1,:].sum()))
print r
```

Still, maybe it's just a very unlikely scenario to get it to converge to an interesting distribution. Is there a proof? If not, does anyone see a counterexample?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Counter-example:

Throw a fair die and define events:

\begin{align}
A &= \{1,2,3,4\} \\
B &= \{2,3,4,5\} \\
C &= \{1,2,3,5\}. \\
\end{align}

Then

\begin{align}
& P(ABC)=1/3 \\
& P(AB)=P(AC)=P(BC)=1/2 \\
& P(A)=P(B)=P(C)=2/3 \\
& \\
\text{So}\quad &P(ABC)=P(A)P(BC)=P(B)P(AC)=P(C)P(AB) \\
\text{But}\quad &P(ABC)=1/3\neq 8/27 = P(A)P(B)P(C).
\end{align}

Comment: Cool. The reason I asked the question is because a lot of resources on "naive Bayesian classifiers" in machine learning state independence assumptions that are way too weak (like pairwise independence, or independence of every variable on all the rest). Even the scipy documentation does this: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/naive_bayes.html. Of course nobody gives a proof, they just say "it simplifies to...". So either I've gone crazy or they're just wrong.

Comment: @gus I'm no expert on Naive Bayes. But my reading of it is that pairwise independence is not sufficient but complete independence is not necessary, which may be why the sources don't state it.
It just needs sufficient conditional independence to replace every instance of the form $P(x_i|y,x_1,\ldots,x_{i-1})$ to $P(x_i|y)$. The ordering of the "factor" variables $x_1,\ldots,x_n$ is
arbitrary and you only need one such ordering to have the required independence to make all the replacements valid. Note that if you changed the ordering to one where the replacements weren't valid then it ...

Comment: @gus ...would still work because the invalid replacements cancel each other out. Eg: Draw a number $1-8$. Events $A=\{1,2,3,4\},B=\{3,4,5,6\},C=\{2,4,7,8\}$. Chain rule gives $P(ABC)=P(A)P(B|A)P(C|AB)$. Simplify to
$P(ABC)=P(A)P(B)P(C)$ under assumptions $A\bot B$ and $C\bot B|A$, both of which are true here. But $B,C$ not independent. So full independence (conditional on "class" variable) isn't needed.
But if you use Chain Rule this way: $P(ABC)=P(C)P(B|C)P(A|CB)$, then to get
to $P(A)P(B)P(C)$ you're replacing $P(B|C)$ with $P(B)$ and $P(A|BC)$ with $P(A)$ - both invalid but they cancel out.

Comment: Cool remark. If they did write something like $P(x_i|y, x_1, ..., x_{i-1}) = P(x_i|y)$ for all $i$, there's an ordering which gives a correct factorization, and I'd be okay with it. Still, $P(x_i|y, x_1, ..., x_{i-1}, x_{i+1}, ..., x_n) = P(x_i|y)$ is a different assumption, and there's no way to derive a factorization from it in general. But I'll just stop nitpicking I guess.